# Making sense of Mathematica's Expectation Function

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have trouble understanding Mathematica's Expectation function.
I understand that it is meant to calculate the expected value of a random variable.

```
In[69]:= Expectation[2 x, x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[10, 10]]
Out[69]= 2

In[70]:= Expectation[3 x, x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[10, 10]]
Out[70]= 3

In[71]:= Expectation[1 x, 1 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[10, 10]]
Out[71]= Expectation[1, 1 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[10, 10]]
```

Should the final evaluation not give back 1 instead of just returning the same expression back?

Comment: I would guess that you need to `Clear[x]` prior to your calculations. The `Expectations` are `20`, `30`, and `x`. Although in the last case it makes no sense to say that a constant has a distribution.

Comment: Bob Hanlon was correct.

Answer (score 2):

It appears I had inadvertently assigned a value to 'x'.

Comment: You can use the comments under your post for clarifications.